# How to exclude undefined parameters in a closure?

Tags: javascript, parameters, scope, closures, undefined

A `JavaScript` practice question on `closures` says the following:

Change the function to support multiple function calls:

```
function joinWords(a, b) {
    return console.log(a + ' ' + b);
}
```

See example cases below for example inputs and their expected outputs.

**Input 1:** 
const greet = joinWords("Hello");
greet("world);
**Output 1:** 
"Hello World"

**Input 2:**
const greet = joinWords("Hey", "there!");
greet("Where", "is", "Foo", "Bar?");
**Output 2:**
"Hey there! Where is Foo Bar?"

For the solution, I've successfully implemented a closure, but I'm still console logging undefined parameters. AKA, for the first test case (Input 1 and Output 1) I'm outputting *Hello undefined World undefined undefined undefined.* How can I elegantly exclude undefined parameters here?

```
function joinWords(a, b) {
    return function(c, d, e, f) {
    console.log(
        a + ' ' + b + ' ' + c + ' ' + d + ' ' + e + ' ' + f
    );
  };
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be looking for [*rest parameters*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/rest_parameters), which make the function accept any number of arguments and passes them over as an array (which one can then call the `.join` method on):

```
 function joinWords(...values) {
   return values.join(" ");
 }
```